# XLA rng-bit-generator takes too much memory

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tpu, xla

XLA allocates 4G of memory to this tensor. The size of which seems to scale with the batch size. Which doesn't make sense to me, it doesn't seem to be part of the model graph to be stored in HBM. I use a TPUv3.

I don't use any random operation apart from initialization of the model. Moreover I declared bfloat16 for all weights, but this is a u32 tensor.

```
  Largest program allocations in hbm:

  1. Size: 4.00G
     Shape: u32[128,8,1024,1024]{3,2,1,0:T(8,128)}
     Unpadded size: 4.00G
     XLA label: %rng-bit-generator = (u32[2,128]{1,0:T(2,128)}, u32[128,8,1024,1024]{3,2,1,0:T(8,128)}) rng-bit-generator(u32[2,128]{1,0:T(2,128)} %fusion.2446), algorithm=rng_default
     Allocation type: HLO temp
     ==========================
```

What could be the reason for the above allocation? I use pixelsnail from: https://github.com/kamenbliznashki/pixel_models

**Questions:**

- Why does this tensor have a type of `u32`, when all my weight / model definitions (including a global enviromental flag) use BF16?
- Why is rng-bit-generator used?

Comment: Looks reasonable: 4 GB = 128 * 8 * 1024 * 1024 * 4

Comment: @Andrey it is correct, no doubt. However I can't find if it correspond to any component of my model. Moreover the rng-bit-generator is even more unclear as to why it is necessary. Also it uses u32 and not the bfloat16 I have specified.